# Multi dimensional hash sort - Perl

Tags: perl

I really need some help in understanding this hash and processing it with sort.

Here is the hash:

```
$VAR1 = {

    Key1:Key1_si => {

        'KeyA' => {
            Keya => 'abcd, defg',
            keyb => '1000',
            keyc =>  '80%',
            keyd =>  '2011.10.09',
            keye => '1234-UR-DDDD',
            keyf => 'rwh',
            keyg => '600',
            keyh => 'red',
            keyi => '900',
            keyj => '',
            keyk =>'int4678_tt',
        },

        'KeyB' => {

            Keya => 'abcd, defg',
            keyb => '2000',
            keyc =>  '100%',
            keyd =>  '2011.11.09',
            keye => '1234-UR-DDDD',
            keyf => 'rwh',
            keyg => '500',
            keyh => 'red',
            keyi => '400',
            keyj => '',
            keyk =>'int4678_tt',
        },
    },

};
```

Question: I want to sort this hash on the basis of 'keyc' whose value is varied. So, I want to sort on the basis like below:

```
Key1:Key1_si->KeyB->Keyc

Key1:Key1_si->KeyA->keyc
```

Also, I want to have the output with the sorted values along with the rest of attributes like :

Print:

```
Key1:Key1_si KeyB Keya keyd Keyc keyf

Key1:Key1_si KeyA keya keyd Keyc keyf
```

Can somebody please help me with the code in perl to perform sort as mentioned above. I will really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Hashes cannot be sorted.  You can output the contents of a hash in a given order by iterating over its keys in an order of your choosing, but there is no ordering of the contents of a hash itself.  It is a bag of indeterminate ordering.

Comment: Do you know any Perl? We are here to help you if you have tried your best to solve a problem but cannot progress any further, but this site is not a free programming service. You should at least show us some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried with 2 codes:

Comment: Code 1: my %fhash = 
   map {
        my @fh;
 for my $val ( keys %hash ) {
 
        foreach  my $sub_Val ( keys %{$hash{$val}) {
               foreach my $misc_info (sort keys %{$hash{$val}{$sub_Val}} )  {
#  print "$misc_info\n";
  if ($misc_info =~ m/keyc/) {
                       push @fh, (join(" $; ", $val, $sub_Val, $misc_info) => $disk_stats{$val}{$sub_Val}{$misc_info});
 }
 }
}
}
        @fh;
   } keys %disk_stats;

foreach (sort { $fhash{$b} <=> $fhash{$a} } keys %fhash) {
#print " $_\n"; 
    printf("%s\t%d\n", join("\t",split(/$;/, $_)), $fhash{$_});
#print "$fhash{$_}\n";
}

Comment: In the above code I am getting the sorted values for keyc. However, if I try to take other values that is if I store other attributes in another hash that is "fhash" it sorts on every attribute which is what I do not want. I just want to sort on "keyc" and want other attributes to be printed. Can you please help with it. I appreciate your response and time.

Comment: Can someone please help?  I will really appreciate your help. I have gone nuts working on it.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own question. Especially after an answer was provided.

Comment: @user1985039 you shouldn't delete the text to a thankyou when it's been answered, other people may have the same issues and these answers can help :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to sort a list of key pairs, so you have to start by building a list of key pairs. A reference to an array is the obvious answer. Once you've figured this out, everything is straight forward.

Building the list of keys:

```
my @unsorted_keys;
for my $k1 (keys(%$VAR1)) {
   for my $k2 (keys(%{ $VAR1->{$k1} })) {
      push @unsorted_keys, [ $k1, $k2 ];
   }
}
```

Sorting those key:

```
my @sorted_keys = sort {
   my ($a_k1, $a_k2) = @$a;
   my ($b_k1, $b_k2) = @$b;

   ( my $a_pc = $VAR1->{$a_k1}{$a_k2}{keyc} ) =~ s/%//;
   ( my $b_pc = $VAR1->{$b_k1}{$b_k2}{keyc} ) =~ s/%//;

   $a_pc <=> $b_pc
} @unsorted_keys;
```

Iterating over the sorted keys:

```
for (@sorted_keys) {
   my ($k1, $k2) = @$_;
   my $hash = $VAR1->{$k1}{$k2};
   ... do stuff with %$hash ...
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for this explanation ikegami. Let me try this and I will get back to you on this whether I am able to get it or not. Thanks a lot for your help and making me understand.

Comment: That's assuming there can be multiple keys at the top level. This simplifies greatly if there's only one (even if it's not always `Key1:Key1_si`).

Comment: Yes, there are multiple keys that is key1:key1_s1. i am still working on it. Please do reply when I get back once I am done completely implementing your explanation. It is really very nice of you. Thanks, Krishna

Comment: i AM Unable to get the solution. It gives me all addresses from @sorted_keys . Can you please provide me some clear solution so that I can implement it. I am not at all an expert. Have started using perl and have come across this problem for which I need some help. I 'll look forward for responses. Thanks a lot for your help. Krishna

Comment: I don't understand your request. I already gave you working code in my answer. (Oops, I used `$VAR` instead of `$VAR1` in one place. Fixed.)

Comment: Hi Ikegami, It worked the way I wanted. I am very thankful to you for your help.

Comment: Output: Key1:Key1_si KeyB 100% abcd, defg
Key1:Key1_si KeyA 80% abcd, defg